# Filling NA's in a data frame according to a rule at R

Tags: r

Let I have such a data frame(df):

```
date           x     y
01-01-2016    43    14
02-01-2016    32    NA
03-01-2016    42    NA
04-01-2016    35    19
05-01-2016    45    NA
06-01-2016    65    NA
07-01-2016    39    NA
08-01-2016    39    24
```

I want to add two  new colums(z1 and z2) to the above data frame(df)

```
date           x     y    z1     z2
01-01-2016    43    14    14     14
02-01-2016    32    NA    14     19 
03-01-2016    42    NA    14     19
04-01-2016    35    19    19     19
05-01-2016    45    NA    19     24
06-01-2016    65    NA    19     24
07-01-2016    39    NA    19     24
08-01-2016    39    24    24     24
```

z1 rule is like below:

- If y_t is not NA z1_t=y_t
- If y_t is NA  then z1_t is equal to the closest previous value of y which is not NA.

z2 rule is like below:

- If y_t is not NA z2_t=y_t
- If y_t is NA  then z2_t is equal to the closest future value of y which is not NA.

How can I do that in R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a *forward fill* (z1) and a *backward fill* (z2); You can do this with `zoo::na.locf` by specifying the `fromLast` parameter, the docs as below:

> logical. Causes observations to be carried backward rather
>   than forward. Default is FALSE. With a value of TRUE this corresponds
>   to NOCB (next observation carried backward)

```
library(zoo)
df$z1 <- na.locf(df$y, fromLast = FALSE)
df$z2 <- na.locf(df$y, fromLast = TRUE)
df
#        data  x  y z1 z2
#1 01-01-2016 43 14 14 14
#2 02-01-2016 32 NA 14 19
#3 03-01-2016 42 NA 14 19
#4 04-01-2016 35 19 19 19
#5 05-01-2016 45 NA 19 24
#6 06-01-2016 65 NA 19 24
#7 07-01-2016 39 NA 19 24
#8 08-01-2016 39 24 24 24
```

Or a `tidyverse` approach, with the `fill` function where you can specify the `direction` up/down:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(z1 = y, z2 = y) %>% 
    fill(z1, .direction = "down") %>% 
    fill(z2, .direction = "up")

#        data  x  y z1 z2
#1 01-01-2016 43 14 14 14
#2 02-01-2016 32 NA 14 19
#3 03-01-2016 42 NA 14 19
#4 04-01-2016 35 19 19 19
#5 05-01-2016 45 NA 19 24
#6 06-01-2016 65 NA 19 24
#7 07-01-2016 39 NA 19 24
#8 08-01-2016 39 24 24 24
```

Comment: For R newbies, don't forget to `install.packages("zoo")`